# Chinese game similar to Minecraft

Tags: game-identification

Could someone help me identify this game?
Just saw it on TV in a Chinese restaurant (in China). Looks like a Minecraft-like game for children.

My search showed that it could be Mini World: Block Art (迷你世界) or Handcraft Planet. But it's unclear if these are just different names for the same game or different games.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: They are separate games, one developed by Miniwan, the other by Tencent.

Comment: Wow! I thought this question would be harshly downvoted (as my previous question from this category), but somehow it got positive response and 2500 views already. How come it's so popular? 

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Looking at your previous question from 2018, it was a identification request of a seemingly very popular game and was likely down-voted due to lack of research. Identification research for less popular games, such as this one, sometimes do attract more upvotes because their harder to track down. It could also be that you mentioned Minecraft, so it probably got a lot of attention because of that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This looks to be the game [Mini World: Block Art](https://www.miniworldgame.com). I discovered this by doing a Google image search, finding a video on Youtube completely in Chinese, and using Google Translate to translate the text to English.

On the [news page](https://www.miniworldgame.com/index.php/news), you can see a picture of the same Dinosaur skin in one of their content updates as shown in your 3rd screenshot.

[image: Skins]